# Sql Server Express db size limit

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

After looking at one of our databases I'm finding it confusing if I'm reaching the limit for a sql express db. The database was created with sql server express 2005 but later migrated to express 2008 r2. I understand that as of 2008 databases have 10gb limits but does that mean the database has to be created in 2008 or when I migrated it over it acquired 5gb of extra space.

Properties window of db in question.
[image]

sp_spaceused query
[image]

and is there anything I can do to free up space. I ran shrink db in SSMS Wizard but it didnt seem to free up any space.

Comment: Do you have any warning or what makes you think that you are running out of space?

Comment: archive off old data, or maybe just pay for sql server?

Comment: The limit was increased to 10 GB as of SQL Server **2008 R2** Express (not **2008**!)

Comment: And that is DATABASE limit, not LOG limit - the LOG can grow to terabytes if you are not using it properly and get rid of the data with backups or the proper backup model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a 4750 MB database of which 4580 MB are used for the transaction log of which are more than 98% in use. You have either a huge uncommitted query or you have the Full Backup Recovery Model and you do not backup your log.

Right click the database in Management Studio and open the properties. Select "Files"  - i guess the size of the transaction log is much bigger than that of the database file.

Select "Options". See what Recovery model is present. Switch it to simple and after a while another DBCC SHRINKDATABASE should free the log space.

Comment: This translates to: your databas is tiny - less than 200MEGAbyte. It is just slopiness in handling the transaction log that made it run out of proportions - and the Tx log is not part of the database size limit ;)

Comment: Note that if you do switch to simple recovery, you won't be able to do a point-in-time recovery. If you need to be able to do point-in-time recoveries, you could also just increase the number of transaction log backups.

Answer (score 1):

You can always truncate the log file with [SHRINKFILE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189493%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), I believe it will free enough space so you won't have to worry.

Example:

```
USE [dbname]
BACKUP LOG [dbname] WITH TRUNCATE_ONLY

DECLARE @InternalLogName VARCHAR(64)
SELECT TOP 1 @InternalLogName = RTRIM(LTRIM(name)) FROM sysfiles WHERE groupid = 0
DBCC SHRINKFILE (@InternalLogName)
```